# Why is $\frac{du}{d\phi} = \frac{1}{D \cdot tan(\alpha)}$?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes

I've started reading this [paper](https://github.com/Python-simulation/Black-hole-simulation-using-python/blob/master/Black%20hole%20simulation.pdf) where it describes light trajectories on a Schwarzschild spacetime and stumbled upon the following formula:

$$\frac{du}{d\phi} = \frac{1}{D \cdot tan(\alpha)}$$ 

Where $u = \frac{1}{D}$.

Why is it that $\frac{du}{d\phi} = \frac{1}{D \cdot tan(\alpha)}$? Is there any intuition behind this formulation? And can it be geometrically or analytically proven?[image]

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/473898/2451

Comment: The old post was poorly worded by myself and didn't link the paper url, so I reposted this one.